# Shiny for R DT: how to read / retain page length and column visibility

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I am quite new to the application, so forgive me if it is obvious. I have a datatable that can be recalculated based on a map center. It works fine. However I would like to read and retain (preserve) certain settings: namely page length and columns visibility. At the moment if a user changes to 20 entries per page and moves the map, it re-renders it with default page length and column vis (using colvis in buttons). I thought i could store it in some variable and retrieve it when re-rendering the table, but not sure how to read from inside the options.
it is built in R Studio for Shiny
Any ideas?

EDIT: I got the data about the page length and column visibility using option stateSave = TRUE and then reading input$Btable_state$length (and i can read as well what columns are visible), but now my issue is: when re-rendering a table it goes to NULL value first, overwriting whatever is stored in input$Btable_state. How can i capture and affect it only if it is altered by changes to the filters, not by the activity of re-rendering the table itself?

EDIT2: as my application requires connection to my google sheets what would not be replicable it can be tried on following example from Github (vnijs/dt_state). How to preserve the nondefault page length (for example 50) when reordering columns (but without linking the action to the selectizeInput, just keeping the last correct state)

```
#ui.r
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("ui_view_vars"),
      tags$a(id = "refresh", href = "#", class = "action-button",
             list(icon("refresh"), "Clear state"),
             onclick = "window.location.reload();")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabPanel("View", DT::dataTableOutput("dataviewer")

      )
    )
  )
))

#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

dat <- iris

## store state in global environment for now
if (!exists("r_state")) r_state <- list()

## Only used from a 'clean' start
r_state$dataviewer_search_columns <- list("","2.5...4","","","[\"setosa\"]")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui_view_vars <- renderUI({
    vars <- colnames(dat)

    ## using selectizeInput with drag_drop and DT
    selectizeInput("view_vars", "Select variables to show:", choices  = vars,
                   selected = vars, multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(plugins = list('remove_button', 'drag_drop')))
  })

  ## make nested list
  mknl <- function(x) list(search = x)

  observeEvent(input$dataviewer_search_columns, {
    r_state$dataviewer_search_columns <<- input$dataviewer_search_columns
  })

  observeEvent(input$dataviewer_state, {
    r_state$dataviewer_state <<- input$dataviewer_state
  })

  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    r_state <<- list()
  })

  output$dataviewer <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$view_vars)

    search <- r_state$dataviewer_state$search$search
    if (is.null(search)) search <- ""

    DT::datatable(iris[,input$view_vars],
                  filter = list(position = "top", clear = TRUE),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  selection = "none",
                  options = list(
                    stateSave = TRUE,
                    searchCols = lapply(r_state$dataviewer_search_columns, mknl),
                    search = list(search = search, regex = TRUE),
                    order = {if (is.null(r_state$dataviewer_state$order)) list()
                      else r_state$dataviewer_state$order},
                    processing = FALSE
                  ),
                  callback = DT::JS("$(window).unload(function() { table.state.clear(); })")
    )
  })

  output$tbl_col_search <- renderPrint(input$dataviewer_search_columns)

})
```

Comment: how many tables you have 1?

Comment: two tables, sorry should have mentioned, they are not related in terms of content and i want to retain only on one (but do not mind if it retains on both)

Comment: Do you want the same number per page for both?

Comment: i wanted to keep whatever the user selected from the list (or using the button colvis for visibility)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, have a look at the example below, it should preserve your paging. Note that I added the button which should render everything to the first value from scratch. Please have a look at [A client-side table](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/) example and the [2.2 DataTables Information](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) page also.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(actionButton("Go","Go"),DT::dataTableOutput('x1'))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  tableparams <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$Go,{
    if(is.null(input$x1_rows_current)){
      tableparams$pageLength <- 5
    }
    else{
      tableparams$pageLength <- length(input$x1_rows_current)
    }
  })
  my_data <- eventReactive(input$Go,{iris})
  output$x1 = DT::renderDataTable(datatable(my_data(),options = list(pageLength = tableparams$pageLength)))
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, and what would be the name of column visibility property?

Comment: additionally, the action is linked to the button Go, if i wanted it to be automatic (with no click action) how shall i do it? The table can be re-rendered by: change of zoom, change of pan, change of date filter - there are far too many actions to attach it to.

Comment: Last but not least - if a user selects 25 entries per page, but current filtered view has only lets say 21 entries, then all next views will have 21 as page length, if I am correct in understanding

Comment: @Slav can you provide a minimal example so then i can re-write mine, there must be a reactive expression that you are using with the map that will trigger the table. I can probably invoke the table columns too as there is a property. For the last point you can round this to nearest 5, either with `top` of `sealing` function calls

Comment: too many characters when i wanted to paste;(, let me simplify it

Comment: rounding up would not be the way to go as a search might return for example 3 records, while an average search results might be dozens. A user would accept the next search to have only 3 results (or 5 if rounded up) if they do not look at the bottom of the table (3 of 56). I am correctly capturing the pagelength with stateSaveParams, but when the page rerenders it gets back the default value I do not know how to avoid

Comment: Again without a good reproducible example I cannot help you fully

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar need, and these are my findings:

- to automatic watch page length value with the method of calculating from current rows will need a reactive expression (instead of a button). However this doesn't work because current rows will change to invalid when table refreshes, which prevent the reactive expression evaluate (it will simple stop, you cannot skip it by checking null)
- your original solution actual can work better, but we need to be more specific, observe the page length change instead of the whole state. `observeEvent(input$dataviewer_state$length`. You problem was NULL triggered the event. Maybe it's update in shiny, now observeEvent doesn't trigger by NULL by default. See help about `ignoreNULL` in `observeEvent`
- when using stateSave = TRUE, it will save state in html5 local storage, which will be kept across session, even when R global environment is empty, this may confuse users. I used `stateDuration = -1` to use session storage instead of local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `JS callback` which retrieves `page.info` when drawn. Observe the event and assign to a `reactiveVal()` which invalidates the DT and retains the DT `pageLength`.

```
makeDatatable <- function(df) {
DT::datatable(
  data = df,
  callback = DT::JS(
    "table.on('draw.dt', function() {
      var page = table.page.info();
      Shiny.onInputChange('page_info', page);
    });",
  options = list(paging = TRUE, 
                 pageLength = page_len, 
                 lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 50, 100))
  )}
)

page_len <- shiny::reactiveVal(13) # default

observeEvent(input$page_info, {

  page_len(input$page_info$length)
})

output$dt <- DT::renderDT(
  expr = { makeDatatable(df, page_len()) })
```