# In R ShinyProxy, how do I get the order of columns from a DT::datatable after a user has re-ordered them using extensions = 'ColReorder'?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a Shiny app in ShinyProxy which requires user login to access.  I have a DT::datatable in the app which allows the user to re-order the columns (there are about 20-30 columns of data, so it's a pain to re-order them).  If they re-order the columns first, then use any filters/slicers, the columns are re-ordered back to the default; if they leave the app and re-open it, the columns are back to the default order.

I'd like to give the user a "save column order" ActionButton and then store those settings per user in a Redis so that when they use filters and/or leave and re-enter the app, they have their preferred column order instead of the default that I've set up - want to make it easy on them!!

I've found this site (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) which gets me close, but no cigar.  I was thinking it may be something like `input$tableId_columns_all` or `input$tableId_columns` - however, those didn't work/returned NA.

I've tried significant googling and most things I find that seem like they'd get me my answer are either Python or jQuery, which I don't believe would solve my problem.

I'm open to suggestions which follow the ActionButton + redis method I've thought of or completely different idea, too!  I'm really just looking to save user settings in ShinyProxy.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you can save/restore the order but here is how you can get the order:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "table.on('column-reorder', function(e, settings, details){",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('colOrder', details.mapping);",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("columnsOrder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[1:5,], extensions = "ColReorder", 
              callback = JS(js), 
              options = list(
                colReorder = TRUE
              )
    )
  })

  output[["columnsOrder"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["colOrder"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm running into memory issues with this same project now (urgh), so I'm working on fixing that first, but I think what you shared above should work!!  I'll mark it as the answer once I can confirm - thank you for the help!

Comment: this worked like a charm!  really easy to understand your answer, too - thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `stateSave = TRUE` in the `datable` `options` might be a solution, too. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182261/shiny-for-r-dt-how-to-read-retain-page-length-and-column-visibility) post.

Answer (score 0):

I come really late with my solution but this could be of interest for some of you. Here, we get the final names of the column header.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


newjs <- 'table.on("column-reorder", function(e, settings, details){
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead");
    var ths = thead[0].getElementsByTagName("th");
    var tableFields = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {
        tableFields[i] = ths[i].innerHTML;            
    }
    Shiny.onInputChange("colOrder", tableFields); 
});
'


ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl"),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("columnsOrder")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[1:5,], extensions = "ColReorder", 
              callback = JS(newjs), 
              options = list(
                colReorder = TRUE
              )
    )
  })

  output[["columnsOrder"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["colOrder"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```